# Why cant I see the changes Entity Framework is trying to make in the SQL 2008R2 Profiler?

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework-5, sql-server-profiler

My code raises an update exception when I call my context SaveChanges.
I am using Entity Framework 5 code first.

I want to see the SQL  EF is trying to run in the profiler, so I can figure out what field I have missed populating.

The profiler displays some select statments but no update.
How can I see the SQL that EF was attempting to use?

The error message is:

```
System.Data.UpdateException occurred
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.
  Source=System.Data.Entity
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.DependencyOrderingError(IEnumerable`1 remainder)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to update your question and show how the concerned entities look like?

Comment: How could the structure of my entities affect whether I can see the SQL in the profiler?

Comment: It might be an issue that comes from the way you defined your foreign keys or something related to the structure